# Intersection of MultiPolygon and Polygon by using DbGeography

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, geospatial

I am trying to get entities from the intersection `DbGeography` column which has `MultiPolygons` inside and a `Polygon` which is the boundary box

```
var sqlPoly = SqlGeography.Parse(bbox); //bbox is in WKT format

if (sqlPoly.EnvelopeAngle() >= 90)
    sqlPoly = sqlPoly.ReorientObject();

var box = DbGeography.FromBinary(sqlPoly.STAsBinary().Value); //resulting bbox is OK and tested by parsing WKT

var query = from ls in _mdb.Listings where box.Intersects(ls.Geo) select ls;
```

So the result is highly weird. I am selecting a bbox which is thousand miles away from the db result set but this query still returns results.

I believe it is an issue about MultiPolygons.

EDIT:

I tried to eliminate Entity Framework and used Raw SQL but result is same:

```
var q = "DECLARE @g geography; SET @g = geography::Parse('" + box.AsText() + "'); SELECT * FROM Listings WHERE @g.STIntersects(Geo) = 1;";
```

When I change `STIntersects` with `STContains` or `STWithin` the resulting sets get filtered but this time; it is too much filtered too many missing geographies appearing.

Comment: Without sample data, it's hard to say what's going on. But with geospatial, I typically like to plot the relevant items on a map to make sure that what I think the data represents is what it actually represents. It's easy to do something like have a polygon the the entire Earth minus the area you're actually concerned about, for example. It looks like you're accounting for that in your definition of `sqlPoly` (which I assume is your bounding box), but I don't make any such assumptions about the data in your DB table. It's good to validate your assumptions.

Comment: I am doing tests on a map actually. This query prepares  a resulting set which is being served on a GeoJson service. This service is making queries according to the visible bounding box as you clearly indicated. I am trying to validate all assumptions but the only possibility is an issue with multi polygons because polygons seem to be filtered on STIntersects but multi polygons not :(

Comment: All I could think of is that for some reason that `STIntersects()` only worked with scalar polygons (i.e. not MULTIPOLYGON() geography instances), but I just did a simple proof of concept where I was able to show that it does work. I still suspect something specific to your data and not with how STIntersects() works. But without being able to look at your data, it'll be difficult to diagnose.

Comment: How can I send you a sample backup? I will appreciate if you may check it :(

Comment: Placing a db backup on Dropbox or similar should do the trick. I'd be happy to give it a look.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_cL-YTvH6m2cThJYmJ3OFd1N3M/view?usp=sharing here it is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've created a chat room to discuss. Join me here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/96487/intersection-of-multipolygon-and-polygon-by-using-dbgeography?tab=general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample data that you gave me, many of the objects have what is called a ring orientation problem. Simply stated, the order in which you specify the corners of a geography polygon matter. That is to say ABCDA <> ADCBA. Luckily the fix is simple. I ran the following update on the sample table:

```
update l
set Geo = Geo.ReorientObject()
from Listele as l
where Geo.EnvelopeAngle() = 180
```

And now when I run a select on the data, it appears to represent a city with some rivers (or perhaps streets) flowing through it. Which I'm guessing is much more what you're looking for.